# process.env in Node: Reading operation = performance penality?

Tags: node.js

In my node.js app, I use dotenv to load an .env file.
I was wondering if reading process.env variables brings a performance penality, or are they just like regular global variables when it comes to read / write speed ?
Or should I cache them with another variable like var ENV_VAR = process.env.VAR ?

Answer (score 1):

`process.env.SOME_VAR` executes system level C code, and is much slower than reading a global variable.  It is recommended to read all `env` variables at startup time (perhaps in a single module), and then use this module to get the values in other code paths.

Comment: "It is recommended" by whom? Could you point us to some authoritative source for this information?

Comment: @JordanRunning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138302/is-process-env-node-env-still-slow-in-node-8

Answer (score 0):

Just like global variables - pretty much no difference in speed.