# Is process.env.NODE_ENV still slow in Node 8

Tags: node.js

I'd heard on the grapevine a while ago that reading from `process.env` is a hit to performance in Node. I wondered if someone can clarify whether this is still the case, and calls to process.env should be avoided or whether it makes no difference to performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any source for your info.  It is common for code to base it's behavior based on the value of NODE_ENV as it has become a somewhat standard practice.  Read this article: [The drastic effects of NODE_ENV](https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/the-drastic-effects-of-omitting-node_env-in-your-express-js-applications/).  I'm wondering if what you read was how much slower node may run when it is not set to "production".

Comment: You can set those variables in some arbitrary .js file as well and then it only gets called once. 
`const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;`

Comment: @jfriend00 You have some references to that, like in the expressJS doc : 

`Be aware that checking the value of any environment variable incurs a performance penalty, and so should be done sparingly` (https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html)

Comment: @Seblor - Yeah, so check it upon module initialization and cache the value locally.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree that's the best solution.

Comment: I think of it like loading a configuration.  You don't read the configuration every time you need it.  You read it upon startup and then save whatever config value you need to use at runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set up your own test for this using process.hrtime(), let's try reading it a bunch of times and see what we get:

```
const time = process.hrtime();
const NS_PER_SEC = 1e9;
const loopCount = 10000000;

let hrTime1 = process.hrtime(time);

for (var i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) 
{
    let result = process.env.TEST_VARIABLE
}

let hrTime2 = process.hrtime(time);

let ns1 = hrTime1[0] * NS_PER_SEC + hrTime1[1]; 
let ns2 = hrTime2[0] * NS_PER_SEC + hrTime2[1];

console.log(`Read took ${(ns2 - ns1)/loopCount} nanoseconds`);
```

The result on my machine (oldish Windows Tower, Node v8.11.2 ):

```
Read took 222.5536641 nanoseconds
```

So around ~0.2 microseconds.

This is pretty fast.. when we talk about performance issues everything is relative. If you really need to read this very frequently, it would be best to cache it.

To make this clear, let's test both scenarios:

```
// Cache
const test = process.env.TEST_VARIABLE;
let loopCount = 10000000; console.time("process.env cached"); for (var i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) { let result = test } console.timeEnd("process.env cached");


// No cache
loopCount = 10000000; console.time("process.env uncached"); for (var i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) { let result = process.env.TEST_VARIABLE } console.timeEnd("process.env uncached");
```

This takes ~10ms when caching, and ~2s when no variable is used to cache the value.

Comment: Your calculation is wrong. It takes around 2.2 seconds on your machine. Try this:

```
const loopCount = 10000000;
console.time("process.env");
for (var i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
{
    let result = process.env.TEST_VARIABLE
}

console.timeEnd("process.env");

```

Comment: Hey @Ville, I think we have some crossed wires here.. I am printing the read time _per read_, not the total. I do agree the total time to read is around 2.2 seconds, but this is to read the variable 10 million (10000000) times. Therefore each read takes ~2.2/10000000 = ~ 0.2 microseconds.

Comment: ah true, it's average read time. by printing it in the end just tricked me to think you were referring to overall time.

Anyways the difference is quite significant: without process.env the time to run the code is 26.755ms on my machine while with process.env it's 2091.082ms, which makes accessing process.env 78.1566809942 times slower. In other words this code gets 78x performance boost by accessing the process.env before for loop.

Comment: Oh yes, it's all relative! If we have to do lots of reads it might be worth caching to a variable.

Comment: To avoid further confusion and provide exact information, might make sense to communicate the performance difference in the answer :)

Comment: Sure thing,  I'll do that!